# Number path: using recursion in a maze-like situation

Tags: python, recursion, path, grid, maze

I'm struggling with an assignment for my CS class. Here are some of the instructions:

---

In this assignment, you will write a program that finds a path through a grid of numbers using a technique called depth-first search.

As input, you will be given a grid of numbers, a start point, an end point, and a target sum. Your task is to find a path that moves orthogonally through the grid, keeping a running total of the numbers along the path, and ending at the end point with the required target sum.

Details:

You can assume that a number grid will be no larger than 10 by 10. An example of a number grid might look like the following:
        34  58  12  10  34
         3  91  10  10  41
        10  76  10   7  12
        10  82  10  81  98
        10  10  10   9  17

The start point will be specified with two numbers, the row number and the column number. Note that when you count rows and columns, you start with zero. Consequently, in the example grid below, we might specify the start point to be row 2, column 0. This would indicate the number 10 directly under the 3.
Similarly, the end point will be specified with a row number and a column number. An end point of row 0, column 3 would point to the 10 in the top row between the 12 and 34.
A target sum is just an integer value that you want your path to sum up to.
If you were given the grid above, with start point (2,0), end point (0,3), and target sum of 100, then you can find a successful path by following the ten 10s in the grid.

Input:

An input file will contain the following:

First line: 7 integers
targetValue, the target sum
grid_rows, the number of rows in the grid
grid_cols, the number of columns in the grid
start_row, the row number of the start point
start_col, the column number of the start point
end_row, the row number of the end point
end_col, the column number of end point
All subsequent lines: there will be (grid_rows) additional lines in the input file. Each line will consist of (grid_cols) integers representing the numbers in the grid for that row.
Here are three examples of input files in which your program should successfully find paths:

pathdata1: this file has a path that is not obvious to find.
pathdata2: this has a smaller, rectangular grid.
pathdata3: this has a larger grid with several dead-end paths. This file is an excellent example of how you can design complex mazes and solve them using your program!
Hints:

Your main program should do the following tasks:
Open the input file "pathdata.txt".
Read the contents of the first line into variables.
Read in the grid. I recommend representing it as a list of lists.
Define a class "Problem", which has as class variables a grid, a path history, a start row and column, and a sum.
Create an instance of class Problem, assigning appropriate values to its instance variables.
Print out the values of the variables and the grid in a nice format. This will ensure you read everything in correctly and built your data structure the way you wanted it. I strongly recommend you define a nice **str** method for class Problem to use here, to show progress as your program executes, and to help you debug.
Call a function "solve", described below.

You should also have a function "solve" which takes a Problem instance as an argument and returns the solution path, if it finds one, or "None" if it doesn't. "solve" should do the following tasks:
Test to see if the Problem instance is a goal state, meaning it's currently at the end state and the sum matches the target sum. If so, print an appropriate message and show the path history.
If it's not a goal state, check to see if the sum exceeds the target sum. If so, print a message and return "None".
Try moving right, if doing so is a legal move. Create a new Problem instance with the appropriate start row/column. Set the current grid point to "None" (to make it as "already visited"). Update the sum and history. Print the new Problem instance, then recursively call "solve" using the instance as an argument. If the recursive call returns a successful path, return the result.
If moving right doesn't work, try moving up, then down, then left.
If none of the attempts succeed, return "None".

It would probably be helpful for you to write a function "isValid" that lets you know if a proposed move is a valid one. isValid would take as arguments a current grid, its size, and a proposed row and column position, and returns True if it's a valid position, False if it isn't. The position would be invalid if you're either trying to move outside the grid boundary, or if you were trying to move to a location already visited by your current path (meaning the location has value "None".

---

That's the instructions. The problem I'm having is with the backtracking. I tried doing it so if the target sum was exceeded, I reset path history, sum and position to what they were before I exceeded and then to continue the maze. But this just got me in an infinite loop where I'd go back, then go to the spot where I exceeded the sum, then go back, etc, etc. Any tips?

I don't want to cheat so just point me in the right direction if you can. Tips for how to implement the solution in my code are appreciated.

Comment: You need some way of keeping track of explored paths so that you don't visit them again.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.  This generic description isn't enough to go on.

Answer (score 0):

What algorithms have you used?  I recommend that you research basic graph traversal algorithms.  [Dijkstra's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) is a good starting point, and is readily available in [generic Python code](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/119466-dijkstras-algorithm-for-shortest-paths/).

The basic idea is that you maintain one list of nodes you've already visited (with the minimum cost to reach each one), and a list of "to-do" nodes to visit ("next", or one step beyond some visited node).  Take the top node off the "to-do" list, add it to the visited list (with the cost to get there), and check each node connected to it.  If the node is unvisited, add it to the "to-do" list with the current cost; if it has been visited, check the cost of getting there and keep the minimum.

Dead ends will die on their own; when you run out of nodes to visit, see which path was the least cost to reach the destination node.